# Emacs displays letters and spaces as newlines until a non-letter/space char is entered

Tags: debugging, c

I am editing a C file, and it suddenly starts moving to a new line instead of showing the character I typed. This seems to be for letters and space.

However, it has saved the characters, and if I type another character which is not a letter or space, the saved characters are correctly displayed.

This has happened to me once before, and I can't figure out what has triggered it.

Saving the file, closing it and reopening it and it continues to misbehave, even closing down Emacs and reopening the file continues with this behaviour. Then suddenly it will start behaving normally, and then again misbehaving. I've tried other C files, and when its in this mood it misbehaves with them all. It does seem to be OK inside quoted strings `"..."`.

Comment: Forgot to add: GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.23, cairo version 1.16.0)
 of 2021-01-18, modified by Debian

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step to repro the bug. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.